# What happens when the process of zeroing out an hard drive is interrupted?

Tags: hard-drive, dd

I was zeroing out my hard drive using the `dd` command and there was an interruption. What does this mean for the hard drive? If I run the command again, will the zeroing take off from where the interruption occurred or will the entire process start all over again?

PS: I use Ubuntu desktop 20.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resuming a DD of an entire disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180330/resuming-a-dd-of-an-entire-disk)

Comment: @Pizza yes it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It means only the first x bytes (up to the interruption) have been zeroed out. If you run the same `dd` command again and don't tell it to skip the first x bytes with `skip=`, it will simply restart writing zeroes from the start of the disk. You'll loose some time, but that's it.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but for general reference I would like to point out that there might be better and more efficient tools:

- SSDs should be erased using [Secure Erase](https://techgage.com/article/securely-erasing-your-ssd-with-linux-a-how-to/). It only takes a few seconds and doesn't wear out the drive.
- If you want to format the drive or make it part of some RAID/ZFS/BTRFS/whatever array, and your commands are complaining about existing file systems, and you just want to remove all traces of them, `wipefs` usually does the job in a few seconds.